# Switching between AES and a highly performant algorithm

Tags: encryption, aes, file-encryption, performance

I want to de/encrypt several binary files rather frequently on a normally battery-powered device. My goal is to use AES-256 when the device is AC-powered and a highly performant algorithm when it's battery-powered to save power. I appreciate that the level of security will be compromised.

Is there a performant algorithm that provides "decent" security? I see that Blowfish fares a bit better according to [this analysis](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-06/ftp/encryption_perf/), but the difference is rather small over AES-128. Given that the paper is almost 10 years old, are there good alternatives out there today?

Is AES-128 supposed to be the standard for something decently secured and highly performant?

Comment: Do you have AES hardware on the device? AES-128 would be secure, but if you don't have hardware there are [faster alternatives](http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-stream.html).

Comment: Yes, there is hardware support, but I was hoping for something to be even faster and less resource consuming. Would it make sense to use chacha though?

Comment: You would have to benchmark it. Hardware implementations are often faster and less resource consuming, but ChaCha is less complex than AES so it could go either way.

Comment: Using AES-NI a modern Intel CPU should be able to en-/decrypt several gigabytes per second. Your IO must be mighty fast to notice that.

Comment: "Is AES-128 supposed to be the standard for something decently secured and highly performant?" Yeah, I guess that the security of AES is kind of the benchmark for symmetric ciphers in the sense that 128 bit is considered enough for even large amounts of plaintext and that attacks on AES do not bring the security level down significantly. There are faster (stream) ciphers though, even though AES is pretty fast.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Intel CPU's are not very likely to be battery powered, unless you include Li-Ion battery packs. On desktop/mobile Intel / AMD CPU's AES-NI certainly makes sense of course.

Comment: If you're going to use a less-secure cipher when on battery, I strongly recommend you use it at all times. It would be trivial for an adversary to downgrade the security to the lowest level, so the higher one buys you nothing but complexity, and complexity is the enemy of security.

Comment: @MrNerdHair I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Why is it better to use a weaker cipher at all times? Surely, AES-256 is stronger than AES-128 or ChaCha, but your suggestion is to use the weaker one at all times?

Comment: +1 to @MrNerdHair.  While _"AES-256 is more secure than AES-128"_ is certainly true, that does not imply that AES-128 is insecure in any way.  Using both does not make your app more secure _(for the reasons he mentioned)_, it just creates more opportunities for security-reducing bugs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation (meaning: all comments, including the ones I cleaned up here) has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29284/discussion-on-question-by-kar-switching-between-aes-and-a-highly-performant-algo). Please feel invited to discuss, rant and rave in that chatroom… while keeping in mind that comments are for clarifications and short notices or messages. Thanks for understanding – Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @MrNerdHair: That depends on your threat model.  If the adversary is in physical possession of the device, then certainly they can unplug AC power.  Not so trivial for a remote opponent to force the downgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [AES-128](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is intended to be the standard block cipher for building a secure and efficient symmetric cryptosystem using some block cipher operating mode, like [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) for encryption or [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) for authenticated encryption; efficiency can be particularly good when there is hardware support for AES and GCM.

There might be better choices in the case at hand, like for a 32-bit CPU [ChaCha](http://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) (perhaps combined with [Poly1305](http://cr.yp.to/mac.html) for authenticated encryption), or one of a plethora of  [lightweight block ciphers](http://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Block_Ciphers). If the device is 8-bit, and speed/efficiency paramount, one might even consider the deprecated and partially broken [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), although its security is questionable even when discarding the beginning of the keystream.

Notice that keeping secret the key of either of these algorithm is hard in a non-security CPU assumed in the hands of an adversary, to the point of being best considered impossible facing a competent and determined adversary. And in a modern security CPU, you might have AES in hardware (thought often, optimized for security rather than speed).

Comment: I don't think RC4 should be recommended when decent security is desired, especially if decent means "similar to AES-128".

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what you mean by keeping the key of is hard for ChaCha? How is it harder than AES?

Comment: @Kar: I mean it is hard to keep a key (or anything) _secret_ in a non-security IC; think JTAG probe.

Comment: When security requirements aren't very high, ChaCha12 (i.e. ChaCha with 12 instead of 20 rounds) might be a good choice.

Comment: @Kar Not to mention the power-consumption side-channel attacks.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, or even ChaCha8, if you want to live on the edge. ChaCha6 and 7 are broken but attacks require over $2^{128}$ ops.

Answer (score 4):

For encryption or decryption of data that is encrypted on the fly, you can do that. For data you store you obviously have to use the same decryption, so if you encrypt a huge file using AES, you have to decrypt it using AES, even when on battery power.

First thing: If there is hardware support for AES, AES will be faster and using less power almost certain.

If you want to use a faster alternative, do the usual thing: look what people with bigger budgets for research and the same problem use.

I know what Google does for TLS. That's not exactly your use-case, but should be close enough.
There are two blog posts I can recommend by [Cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/do-the-chacha-better-mobile-performance-with-cryptography/) and [Google](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/speeding-up-and-strengthening-https.html) (images broken, shame on them).

I will summarize the corner points:
Google was needing a fast and secure cipher that uses less power on mobile devices (say Android). They decided to use the [ChaCha20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#ChaCha_variant) [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) with [Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

It is included in Chrome since late 2013 and the google servers support it. Chrome prefers AES-GCM, if there is hardware support for it and else uses ChaCha20-Poly1305.

This seems like a good choice for you too and should be sufficiently secure. It was a finalist in [eSTREAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTREAM) and also is from [djb](http://cr.yp.to/djb.html), whom I hold in high regard as cryptographer.

Because it is in a similar security league as AES-128, you could also just use the faster of them, if you know the device. If you target multiple devices, I would go the Chrome way and switch between AES and ChaCha, depending on hardware support.

Answer (score 3):

As you said you are OK with a little bit less security in the more performant algorithm, I suggest Speck for that.  It was developed by the NSA, so although some might worry about a backdoor (I personally doubt there is one though I would not know the difference if there were), it probably also means that ordinary people will not break it easily if at all.  Indeed it has been out 2 years and has been analyzed but not broken.  It comes in a variety of key and block sizes.  I actually have C++ code (maybe not the most optimized, but it does pass test vectors) for 32/64 (block size 32, key size 64) and for 128/128.  Will post both in this answer.  They are very fast and small.

32/64

```
#include "Speck.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

#define M 4
#define NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS 22
#define BIG_BIT_SHIFT 7
#define SMALL_BIT_SHIFT 2

#define ROR(x, r) ((x >> r) | (x << (16 - r)))
#define ROL(x, r) ((x << r) | (x >> (16 - r)))
#define R(x, y, k) (x = ROR(x, BIG_BIT_SHIFT), x += y, x ^= k, y = ROL(y, SMALL_BIT_SHIFT), y ^= x)
#define UNR(x, y, k) (y ^= x,y = ROR(y, SMALL_BIT_SHIFT),x ^= k,x -= y,x = ROL(x, BIG_BIT_SHIFT))

void Speck_32_64::generateRoundKeys(uint16_t *K, uint16_t *RK)
{
    uint16_t keyChunks[M];
    keyChunks[0] = K[0];
    keyChunks[1] = K[1];
    keyChunks[2] = K[2];
    keyChunks[3] = K[3];

    uint64_t i;
    uint16_t indexer = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        RK[i] = keyChunks[0];
        indexer = 1 + i % (M-1);
        R(keyChunks[indexer], keyChunks[0], i);
    }
}

void Speck_32_64::encrypt(uint16_t *pt, uint16_t *ct, uint16_t *K)
{
    uint64_t i, B = K[1], A = K[0];
    ct[0] = pt[0]; ct[1] = pt[1];

    uint16_t RK[NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS];
    generateRoundKeys(K, RK);

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        R(ct[1], ct[0], RK[i]);
    }
}

void Speck_32_64::decrypt(uint16_t *pt, uint16_t *ct, uint16_t *K)
{
    uint64_t i, B = K[1], A = K[0];
    pt[0] = ct[0]; pt[1] = ct[1];

    uint16_t RK[NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS];
    generateRoundKeys(K, RK);
    for (i = NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS; i > 0; i--)
    {
        UNR(pt[1], pt[0], RK[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

128/128

```
#include "Speck.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

#define ROR(x, r) ((x >> r) | (x << (64 - r)))
#define ROL(x, r) ((x << r) | (x >> (64 - r)))
#define R(x, y, k) (x = ROR(x, 8), x += y, x ^= k, y = ROL(y, 3), y ^= x)
#define UNR(x, y, k) (y ^= x,y = ROR(y, 3),x ^= k,x -= y,x = ROL(x, 8))

void Speck_128_128::generateRoundKeys(uint64_t *K, uint64_t *RK)
{
    uint64_t i, B = K[1], A = K[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        RK[i] = A;
        R(B, A, i);
    }
}

void Speck_128_128::encrypt(uint64_t *pt, uint64_t *ct, uint64_t *K)
{
    uint64_t i, B = K[1], A = K[0];
    ct[0] = pt[0]; ct[1] = pt[1];

    uint64_t RK[32];
    generateRoundKeys(K, RK);

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        R(ct[1], ct[0], RK[i]);
    }
}

void Speck_128_128::decrypt(uint64_t *pt, uint64_t *ct, uint64_t *K)
{
    uint64_t i, B = K[1], A = K[0];
    pt[0] = ct[0]; pt[1] = ct[1];

    uint64_t RK[32];
    generateRoundKeys(K, RK);
    for (i = 32; i > 0; i--)
    {
        UNR(pt[1], pt[0], RK[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just going to add in the comment here that the header files are basic as can be.  Each header file contains only a static class that holds prototypes of the methods.

Comment: "It's always fascinating to study NSA-designed ciphers. I was particularly interested in the algorithms' similarity to Threefish, and how they improved on what we did. I was most impressed with their key schedule. I am always impressed with how the NSA does key schedules. And I enjoyed the discussion of requirements. *Missing, of course, is any cryptanalytic analysis.*": Bruce Schneier. There is a plethora of lightweight ciphers. I only found one paper describing the security of the ciphers, and the cipher is published by the NSA. I don't expect it to broken, but I leaves some questions....

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, Schneier's blog is where I found Speck, and I noted the same quote you posted.  I did not originally feel confident in it because of the NSA connection.  However if you read further down in his blog, in the comments, you will notice Schneier expressing doubt any backdoor (if there was one) could remain hidden for long.  As for papers on the security of Speck, see https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/320.pdf and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.380.6157&rep=rep1&type=pdf.  Both are attacks on reduced round variants.  Full specification Speck is unbroken.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution depends on the details of your application, but I have one comment and one suggestion.

First the comment: You say you have AES hardware available.  I don't know the details of your platform, but this hardware is likely to be much more efficient in time/power than a software implementation of *any* reasonable encryption algorithm.  You need to do some analysis/benchmarking here.

Now a suggestion that may work (depending on your particular application): If The amount of data that you need to encrypt while on battery power is fairly small, you can use pre-computation while on AC power to help.  For example, while on AC power you can AES encrypt a nonce/counter and store the result.  Then in battery mode you can xor these results with your plaintexts.  So you are effectively implementing AES in CTR mode, but the only operation you need to perform on battery power is an xor.

The above is just an example to get you to think about application-specific alternatives.  Perhaps if you share more details about your application you may get better suggestions.

Comment: If you have AES in hardware, the RAM (or flash) access to load the XOR pad might cost similar power to just doing the AES.  Not sure about that, though.